# Application of the implicit mapping theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, implicit-function-theorem

Show that the equation $x^4 + y^4 -2xy=0$ defines a function $\phi(x)=y$ in a neighborhood of $(1,1)$.

Proof. Let $f(x,y)=x^4+y^4-2xy$. Clearly $f\in C^{\infty}$, and $f$ is continuously differentiable in $A\times B$, which contains the point $(1,1)$. Therefore there exists open sets such that $1_x \in A$, $1_y \in B$ where $f(1,1)=1+1-2=0$. Also the Jacobian of $f$ with respect to $y$ ( In this case it is $D_2 f = 4y^3 - 2x \neq 0$ ) has non-zero determinant when $y\in B$. Therefore the implicit mapping theorem states that for each $x\in A$ there is a unique $\phi(x) \in B$, that is we can solve $y$ in terms of $x$. There is a function $\phi(x)=y$  defined near $(1,1)$.

Is this an accurate application of the implicit mapping theorem?

Comment: This is right (with just a small typo on your derivative). You could go even further and say that the map (at least locally) is given by  $$\phi(x) \sim 1 - (x-1) = 2 - x$$

Comment: What does ∼ mean here?

Comment: $\sim$ is sim, which means they asymptotically go together